# RVM is loading with the wrong version of ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bash, rvm

When I open terminal I see:

```
Last login: Sun Aug 26 15:33:57 on ttys001
Using /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125
Running /Users/me/.rvm/hooks/after_use
Using /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
ruRunning /Users/me/.rvm/hooks/after_use
me-MacBook:site me$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
```

Where I want ruby 1.9.3. If I then type:

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

I get the below:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.3 --default
Using /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
Running /Users/me/.rvm/hooks/after_use
```

This allows me to use rails but when I reopen terminal I have to do this every single time. Is there a way to make this the default setting? I added it to my bash_profile but that does not seem to work. Here is my bash profile:

```
# Required for Ruby upgrade to 1.9.3
export RUBYOPT=-r openssl

export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/local/bin

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function

# Sets the RVM profile on terminal load
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p125
rvm use 1.9.3 --default

# RVM Requirements
export CC="/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2"
export CFLAGS="-O2 -arch x86_64"
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/local/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/local/include"
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386"

# Postgresql
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you run `ruby -v` in command prompt, you are actually running `/usr/bin/ruby` because you set `/usr/bin` in very first of `$PATH` env variable. You should move the following rvm initialize command to the end of bash profile.

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

it should work. You don't need to run `rvm use` command in your bash profile once you set default ruby by `--default` flag.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably delete these lines from your bashrc:

```
# Sets the RVM profile on terminal load
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p125
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

rvm should automatically load it's default profile when you open your terminal, so no need to set (and re-set for some reason) the version in your bashrc.

The `--default` option is only needed once, to indicate the selected version to be the default from then on.

Comment: Tried that, same effect. The terminal still opens with ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 1):

Try `rvm alias create default 1.9.3`.