# RVM Issues - Wrong Version of Ruby

Tags: ruby, bash, rvm

For some time now I've not been able to get the proper version of Ruby functioning automatically with RVM.  New terminals show a version of 2.0.0p481 whilst RVM current and default is set to =* ruby-2.2-head [ x86_64 ].  I've updated rvm (rvm get stable) and new terminals still choose the ancient version.

```
$ which ruby
/Users/rich/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2-head/bin/ruby
```

So it isn't making much sense.  I don't mind starting over from the start, but I'm not sure what to look at.  It's been suggested all my profiles are messed up, but I thought there was only one profile read upon startup, and that's ~/.bash_profile.

Any advice appreciated.  Cheers

Comment: That comment probably was talking about `rvm`/`ruby` profiles and not shell profiles but I don't know anything about all of this so that could be wrong.

Comment: until you figure it out, if you just need something running the current version right now, try using nitrous. it's free, and uses the newest ruby. google their site,  take 2 mins to set up an account and set up a box, and your ready to go

Comment: I just uninstalled rvm and reinstalled it, then grabbed 2.2-head.  This is what it give me now:  "rvm list
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/rich/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2-head/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.2-head'.

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.2-head [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.2.2 [ x86_64 ]"

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134469/rvm-is-loading-with-the-wrong-version-of-ruby

Comment: Unfortunately no.  It's completely within the area that I'm researching, but it hasn't worked so far.  I'm flushing out options for ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed ruby with rvm try:

```
rbenv rehash
```

Or if you want to set up a particular version of ruby use

```
rvm use 2.1.1
rbenv rehash
```